# Excel split based on string

Tags: excel, vbscript, split

I am having below type of values in xls column A

```
Row 1 - 3min 17s 463ms
Row 2 - 19s 364ms
Row 3 - 165ms 
Row 4 - 364ms  
Row 5 - 4min 1s 463ms
```

Form my calculation I need to convert above values into ms (milli seconds), I have tried doing this (with my limited VBScripting knowledge) using split functions but I couldn't make it work :(. Can you please help.

Thank You, 
V2ri.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far. Where did your approach fail?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub millisec()
    Dim A As Range, r As Range, s As String
    Dim N As Long, milli As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set A = Range("A1:A" & N)
    For Each r In A
        v = r.Text
        ary = Split(v, " ")
        milli = 0
        For Each ar In ary
            If Right(ar, 2) = "ms" Then
                milli = milli + CLng(Replace(ar, "ms", ""))
                GoTo qwerty
            End If
            If Right(ar, 1) = "s" Then
                milli = milli + 1000& * CLng(Replace(ar, "s", ""))
                GoTo qwerty
            End If
            milli = milli + 60& * 1000& * CLng(Replace(ar, "min", ""))
qwerty:
        Next ar
        r.Value = milli
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: wow,, its working perfectly... u r genious Gary's Student.. thanks a ton.